# How to avoid calling .map function before the for loop is finished?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `handleForm(formData)`:

```
    handleFormData(formData) {
    const { school, schoolyear } = this.props.params;
    const { addDataToBackend } = this.props;
    const { selectedDate } = this.props.schoolVacationDelivery;

    if (!_.isEmpty(selectedDate)) {
        var structuredFormData = [];
        for (var key in formData) {
            var prefix = key.split("=")[0];
            var appendix = key.split("=")[1];
            var dataObject = structuredFormData.find(o => o.season === prefix);
            if (!dataObject) {
                dataObject = { season: prefix };
                structuredFormData.push(dataObject);
            }
            dataObject[appendix] = formData[key];
        }

        let updatedStructuredFormData = structuredFormData.map(x => {
            let season = x.season;
            x.date = selectedDate.find(e => e.indexOf(season) > -1).split("=")[1];
            return x;
        });

        addDataToBackend(schoolyear, updatedStructuredFormData);
    } else {
        addDataToBackend(schoolyear, []);
    }

    browserHistory.push(
        `/schooladmin/home/school/${school}/schoolyear/${schoolyear}/prepackaged`
    );
}
```

From time to time i get `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` on this line `x.date = selectedDate.find(e => e.indexOf(season) > -1).split("=")[1];`. How can i make sure I don't call the `structuredFormData.map` before by for loop is finished? How can i change the code so its always sure that for loop is ended before I am calling `structuredFormData.map` function?

This is the error output:

[image]

Line 98: `let updatedStructuredFormData = structuredFormData.map(x => { ..`

Line 100: `x.date = selectedDate.find(e => e.indexOf(season) > -1).split("=")[1];`

Comment: Have you ensured that there's anything that fits the `indexOf(season) > -1` conditional inside `selectedDate` when you call `structuredFormData.map()`? The problem is that `selectedDate.find()` returns empty as it cannot find the value you are searching for. Seems that `formData` is invalid as don't has any valid `season`.

Comment: `selectedDate` is an array in Redux, which is always populated with dates. But i think there might be an issue that for loop dont get finished before its calling the next funtion `structuredFormData.map` function.

Comment: No, is impossible for your code to behave that way. The problem is that `selectedDate` don't has the date you are looking for. Your problems comes from elsewhere. Just add some breakpoints and debug your code line by line.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález i have debugged, and i can see there is 2 dates inside `selectedDate` array. What can it might be then?

Comment: I don't know how you fill the `selectedDate` array xD just check how do you fill the array and it `selectedDate` actually has the date `indexOf(season)` is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop doesn't contain any async operations (like API request, `setTimeout`, promises, etc), so JavaScript ALWAYS will execute code inside this loop before `.map`.

It seems that your problems lay outside of `handleFormData` function (for example, with the data in `props` that you use inside of the function).

Check how you get this data and ask for help here again if needed.
Good luck!

Comment: Not a specific answer to a specific problem actually.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Question was: "How can i make sure I don't call the structuredFormData.map before by for loop is finished? How can i change the code so its always sure that for loop is ended before I am calling structuredFormData.map function?"

Comment: Oh, that's true. You're right. I just focused on the error. Can you edit your answer a bit so I can change the vote? It says "You last voted on this answer 6 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: I debugged and debugged and finally found out whats the problem was. Posted a new post to find solution for the problem.